# Accessing Properties From Gradle in Groovy

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

I'm trying to set a variable/property within Gradle during a war build for deployment. However, when I try setting it, it seems it just gets set to null whenever I try accessing it from groovy. I'm building on a local machine with  the command (I've tried both):

`gradle build -Dgrails.env=development -Dtest.variable=/app/testing/development` or `gradle war -Dgrails.env=development -Dtest.variable=/app/testing/development`

Then I deploy the WAR file to a Tomcat server.

But when I try accessing that variable by `System.getProperty("test.variable")` I am receiving a null error on that property. What do I need to do to set a command-line variable in Gradle and have it be accessible in Groovy when I try to deploy the WAR file on a server? I know the grails.env is working as it is reading the proper values in the application.yml file, but I cannot access the given property that I am trying to set.

Comment: System properties are there for the duration of the command - if you run a different command on a different machine it wont be there. What are you trying to achieve? Setting a variable at build time and have it avalible at runtime?

Comment: Exactly that, I'm attempting to set a directory at build time that can differ from machine to machine, and would prefer to set it during a Jenkins build task. I think I may just use a Shell script in Jenkins to substitute some expression I put in within the application.yml and access it that way.

Comment: Instead of building that in at build time why not set/read the system property at runtime in tomcat? That way you build once and run anywhere you'd like without rebuilding the war eachtime.

Comment: The only reason I cannot do that is because I don't have access to the system properties on the system that is running Tomcat. I wish I could, as it would make this a lot easier, but I think I found a way of doing it just with a regular expression replace during a Jenkins job.